# Finding Real/Imaginary part of a square root

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm not sure if this is obvious or not; say I have the function $$f(z)=\left(\frac{z^2}{4}-c^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ where $c$ is constant. Is it possible to expand this into its real and imaginary parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(z) = \sqrt{\frac{z^2-4c^2}{4}} = \frac{\sqrt{z^2-4c^2}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{(z-2c)(z+2c)}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{z-2c})(\sqrt{z+2c})$.

Let $w^2=z-2c$. Now lets write this in polar form, $w^2=|z-2c|e^{\Theta i}$, for $\Theta=Arg(z-2c)$.

Take $r_0:=z-2c$. Thus,
$w^2=|r_0|e^{\Theta i} \Rightarrow w=(|r_0|)^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{\frac{(\Theta+2\pi k)i}{2}}$ for $k=0,1$.

Similarly, for $d^2=z+2c$ after completing this same process we have, $d = (|r_1|)^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{\frac{(\gamma+2\pi k)i}{2}}$ for $k=0,1$.

Hence, $f(z)=\frac{1}{2}((|r_0|)^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{\frac{(\Theta+2\pi k)i}{2}})((|r_1|)^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{\frac{(\gamma+2\pi k)i}{2}})$.

So, yes with some foiling and adding more variables we can express this in it's imaginary and real parts.